# LiveServer (Ritwick Dey) not reloading during inspect element

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, inspect-element, liveserver

New dev here, I'm having issues with my LiveServer in VSCode.

When I open the LiveServer on Chrome and make changes, it'll reload without any problems however, when I inspect element the page and make some changes to my HTML and then save it, the LiveServer doesn't reload and pops up the "No Internet" page. The bottom left will then show "html.offline".

What I've tried (without success) from what I've seen online:

- Changed the extension setting to "Use Local Ip".
- Added "liveServer.settings.port":5501" in the Settings.json
- Disabled and reinstalled ext.
- Updated ext.

Is there anything else someone may know that could be causing the problem?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

try setting your throttling in chrome dev tools to "No throttling". I did this and mine worked.
Press Ctrl+Shift+M then at the top toolbar set to no throttling.